# Should activation function be monotonic in neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

A lot of activation functions in neural networks (sigmoid, tanh, softmax) are monotonic, continuous and differentiable (except of may be a couple of points, where derivative does not exist).

I understand the reason for continuity and differentiability, but can not really understand a reason for monotonisity.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9233/8560, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/25444/8560

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During the training phase, backpropagation informs each neuron how much it should influence each neuron in the next layer.  If the activation function isn't monotonic then increasing the neuron's weight might cause it to have less influence, the opposite of what was intended.  The result would be choatic behavior during training, with the network unlikely to converge to a state that yields an accurate classifier.

Comment: Just to clarify: Gradient descent finds a local minimum even with monotonic activation functions. It might only take longer.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense. There is no argument here to actually connect sentence number 2 and sentence number 3. It's just supposed to be obvious to the reader that because "the opposite of what was intended" and "chaotic behavior" are both bad-sounding things, that therefore one might imply the other. There's nothing here even approaching an *intuition* as to why a non-monotonic activation function might lead to oscillating or diverging loss during gradient descent, which is basically the claim the answer is making.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary for the activation function to be monotonic. The best example of that is  [MISH](https://arxiv.org/vc/arxiv/papers/1908/1908.08681v1.pdf)activation function which is non monotonic activation function and it out performs ReLU activation on various benchmarks.